# dlltool: Fatal error: no compiled in support for x86_64

Tags: windows, dll, 64-bit, dlltool

I'm trying to build a 64-bit version of `libpython27.a` from `python27.dll` on Windows 7 x64.

Following these [instructions](http://rosinality.ncity.net/doku.php?id=python:installing_theano), I tried:

```
E:\temp>gendef python27.dll
 * [python27.dll] Found PE+ image

E:\temp>dlltool --as-flags=--64 -m i386:x86-64 -k --output-lib libpython27.a --i
nput-def python27.def
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: no compiled in support for x86_64
dlltool: as exited with status 1
dlltool: failed to open temporary head file: dgtnh.o: No such file or directory
```

What can explain `Fatal error: no compiled in support for x86_64`?

I see:

```
E:\temp>dlltool -h
Usage dlltool <option(s)> <object-file(s)>
   -m --machine <machine>    Create as DLL for <machine>.  [default: i386:x86-64]
        possible <machine>: arm[_interwork], i386, mcore[-elf]{-le|-be}, ppc, thumb
   -e --output-exp <outname> Generate an export file.
```

Does the issue come from the fact `possible <machine>` does not contain `x86_64`, and if so where to find a `dlltool.exe` that supports `x86_64`?